# UWP detect idle time or inactivity

Tags: uwp, lifecycle

How do I detect Idle time or inactivity in an UWP app? I have already tried LASTINPUTINFO, but it is not allowed in UWP so I am not able to use this.

Comment: Why do you need the idle time? What do you want to do? And also what's the language you are using?

Comment: App has heartbeat reporting back to DB. DB has job , if app hasn't checked in within certain time a notification is sent out. This works, until  device has been idle and Screen Saver starts, placing app in suspended state and heartbeat timer no longer reports to the DB. Looking to detect idle time in the application so we can disable the screen saver and have the application simply navigate to a different page then back to the main page to keep burn in from happening.  The application is a Windows 10 UWP application written in C# and is running in Kiosk (assigned access) mode on the device.